# Ublock Origin custom filter to block ads on all emails from a certain sender?

Tags: email, rss, ublock

I'm subscribed to various email updates through the Blogtrottr rss-feed-to-email updater service. (https://blogtrottr.com/) The emails that are sent all contain large ads. Is there a Ublock Origin custom filter that could block all ads on all emails coming from blogtrottr.com? Is it even possible to block all ads on all emails coming from a certain sender (such as blogtrottr)?

Edit: I'm using gmail.

Thank you very much for any help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Any answers or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom filters for the ad domains, for example filter `##[href*="blogtrottr.com"]` will hide all blogtrottr.com links.